# Formula for scheadule in excel

Tags: excel

I have a problem... I want to create a schedule in excel that will show me if there are enough of people in some specific range of hours. Excel will show me if criteria are met for each day and as a result I want to get a formula True/False (For conditional formatting). Thank you guys!!!

http://www.wifive.pl/aukcje/1.jpg

http://www.wifive.pl/aukcje/2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you split the start and end time in the data entry into two columns formatted as time, you can use COUNTIFS to count up the rows between two dates like they do in this example:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/count-the-number-of-excel-records-that-fall-between-two-dates/

Comment: Thanks! As you may see I used functions 

LEFT(B5,SEARCH(" ",B5,1)-1)
 and
RIGHT(B5,LEN(B5)-SEARCH(" ",B5,SEARCH(" ",B5,1)+1))

to separate start and finish hour from cells. Is there any way to use that, to separate two hours and use it in the function u sent me?